# ANGULAR: How to change the * required in material?

Tags: angular

I want the "*" that is required in input to be color red.
I imported and use reactive forms and angular materials for this. No CSS yet for this because I dont know how to edit it with the required element in input.

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZGt8.png)

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="changePassword()">
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
            <input required type="password"  matInput placeholder="Old password">
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS selector is

```
.mat-placeholder-required.mat-form-field-required-marker {
  color: red;
}
```

[See it in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d594nr?file=styles.css)

Be sure to either make a [deep styling](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) if you style it in your components, or to put in a global styling file, such as `style.css` (like I did)

Comment: @Ren you have the live demo to see it in action. If it doesn't work, then please, provide a demo of your own reproducing the issue.