# customize " *" (space + asterisk) in the required fields for angular material 13+

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, whitespace

Adding an asterisk is the new default behavior in the form fields for Angular Material v13.
However, if you look up carefully, there is a space before the asterisk. On the page it renders (slightly simplified) as:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker"> *</span>
```

If I decide to change the color of the asterisk,
I would use

```
.mat-placeholder-required.mat-form-field-required-marker {
  color: blue;
}
```

as suggested here [ANGULAR: How to change the * required in material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282490/angular-how-to-change-the-required-in-material) or so.

However, **I need to remove the space before the asterisk** so that it looks in the input field as
First name*
instead of
First name *.

Is there a way to customize it?

P.S. Using `[hideRequiredMarker]="true"` and adding a manual asterisk (using First name* as a placeholder) doesn't seem to be an option as far as the project is huge. A common solution is preferable.

Comment: You could apply a bit of negative `margin-left` to that span (preferably in a font-relative unit), that should probably do the trick already ...?

Comment: You can set `display: inline-flex` which will remove all whitespace from text

Answer (score 1):

In your main CSS file (style.css, custom.css), add the below line.

```
.mdc-floating-label--required {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Adjust as necessary.